# Dine at our uncle's (home/house)

Tags: apostrophe, ellipsis

Is it necessary to use a noun (*home*/*house*/*place*/*restaurant*) after the word "uncle's" in this sentence?

> Tomorrow, we shall dine at our uncle's.

Isn't it correct?

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable in casual form unless there is a reason to believe the reader might be confused by ambiguity.  For instance, if you wrote "My uncle has a lovely house and owns his own restaurant.  Tomorrow we shall dine at my uncle's."

Comment: The listener is going to presume the speaker is referring to his uncle's home. If instead dinner is being held in a private jet plane then it's best to add that relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to use the possessive when referring *informally* to a person's home.
For example

> We all had dinner at **Brad's** *(house)*.
>   We watched the game at **David's** *(apartment)*.
>   We spent the night at **Sally's** *(flat)*.